# more calls ajax in the same page for displaying more data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a page that displays some posts: when i click in "other article", i count the number of the articles in a main div and i pass this variable with a ajax call at php script.

```
//JS (ajax)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".otherArticle").click(function() {
        var numPosts = $("#posts > div").length; // get number of post in the page
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "script.php",
            data: {
                'number': numPosts
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {

                $("#posts").html(data) // write in #posts the new data                                                                                                  
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Noob");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My HTML

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="article">...</div>
    <div class="article">...</div>
    <div class="article">...</div>
    <button class="otherArticle"></button>
</div>
```

At the beginning there are 3 articles. When i click "otherArticle", i pass the number of articles at my php script, where i add 5 at the number of my articles. after, i do the query for selecting the other articles with limit of 5+3

```
/*script.php*/
<?php
    //include connect db
    $numberNewPosts= $_GET['number'] + 5 ;
    $query= "select posts from myTab limit 0, ". $numberNewPosts ." ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<div= 'article'> ". $row['posts '] ." </div> ";
    }
    echo "<button class='otherArticle'></button>";
?>
```

If a click one time, its work, and are displayed 8 articles (5+3). But the second time that i click, it doesn't work. I would like that it count 8 articles and it add other 5 articles in my script php. Any ideas?

Comment: "doesn't work" means...it loads the wrong quantity? Or there's an error? Or nothing at all happens? Please be clear, and mention what debugging you've done - e.g. stepping through code, monitoring the ajax request etc in your developer tools to try and resolve it. Then we can have a clearer idea of the issue.

Comment: Having said that, I suspect the issue is probably because you destroy and re-create the "otherArticle" button each time you run the ajax, and of course then the new version of the button is not associated to the Javascript event handler, because it didn't exist when the handler was created. I see no reason to keep destroying and re-creating this button, it never changes its content. Just keep it static on the page to begin with and don't output it from the script which returns the articles.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps the problem is this. There is no error in debugging. Nothing happens simply

Comment: Ok. It's work. That was the problem. I love you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed that @ADyson already answered this question. Solution:

It's because your button is inside the "posts" div. Change your code like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="article">...</div>
    <div class="article">...</div>
    <div class="article">...</div>
</div>
<button class="otherArticle"></button>
```

**PHP**

```
//include connect db
$numberNewPosts= $_GET['number'] + 5 ;
$query= "select posts from myTab limit 0, ". $numberNewPosts ." ";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<div class='article'> ". $row['posts '] ." </div> ";
}
```